# Spring Boot OAuth Authorization and Resource Server

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Boot to create an OAuth Authorization Server and Resource Server. I want these two to be separate modules and run on different ports/servers.

What I don't understand is how to make Resource server communicate with Authorization server? Where and how can I configure Authorization Server details in the Resource Server (properties file or in a Java Class)?

I tried to look for the solution over the internet. I could find many examples but in none of them, I could find the link which connects the Resource Server with the Authorization Server.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

https://spring.io/blog/2018/08/21/spring-security-5-1-0-rc1-released#oauth2-resource-server

If you go up the directory you will find samples for both.

https://github.com/jzheaux/messaging-app/blob/master/resource-server/src/main/java/sample/config/ResourceServerConfig.java